# An issue in sorting the items by relevance in Lucene 2.9

Tags: lucene, search-engine, relevance

We are using Lucene.NET Version 2.9 to search for items using free text query. We get the items automatically sorted by Lucene by relevance. It has been working great except for one odd case. When search for **Agile project management**, the top 4 items returned by Lucene are as follows.

1. Agile Project Management For Dummies
2. Fundamentals of Agile Project Management
3. Agile project management
4. Agile Project Management

The item 3 or 4 should be showing up at the top as they are perfect. In many cases that we searched, if an item matches 100%, it is shown at the top. Anybody can please explain what is happening here. We are using standard analyzier.

Comment: You'd perhaps get more help at http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/

Comment: This isn't what I get...wanna post some source?

Comment: See how Lucene.Net's scoring works http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_4/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd look at is what other fields are included in the search? A description field loaded with the word Agile could be pushing the first two up for example.

Comment: There are only only two fields; one is item unique id, another is item name. While searching, we search only in the item name.